# Javascript Jquery - Dont close if child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Ok i have a script that closes all my divs unless those divs have this class name.  The following script works fine:

```
window.onclick = function(ev){
    if((ev.target.className !== 'ddHeader') && (ev.target.className !== 'ddSubmenu')&& 
    (ev.target.className !== 'ddContainer')&& (ev.target.className !== 'ddItem')){
        delay_close_sub();
    }
};
```

So now i need to do the same thing with a child element.  I would like to just add it to the above code similar to this:

```
window.onclick = function(ev){
    if((ev.target.className !== 'ddHeader') && (ev.target.className !== 'ddSubmenu')&& 
    (ev.target.className !== 'ddContainer')&& (ev.target.className !== 'ddItem') && 
    ev.target.element !== 'ddHeader > input){
        delay_close_sub();
    }
};
```

I added: ev.target.element !== 'ddHeader > input') to the end but it does not work.  How would i make this work?  I want to make sure that when the input field inside the ddHeader div is click it doesn't trigger the "delay_close_sub() function.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery in a much more <strike>efficient</strike> compact way:

```
$(window).click(function(ev){
    if(!$(ev.target).is('.ddHeader,.ddSubmenu,.ddContainer,.ddItem,.ddHeader > input'))
        delay_close_sub();
});
```

Which means if the event target doesn't match any of the comma-separated selectors, close your thing.

Comment: This is not efficient, in fact it's so inefficient I have no words

Comment: The way OP originally had it, performs almost 100 times faster.

Comment: Out of curiosity, @Esailija, do you have a link to a comparison showing the speed difference? Not to contest your assertion, but just because I'm curious to see it for myself... =)

Comment: @Esailija: good grief, that is a noticeable difference, isn't it? O.O Thanks for posting the link!

Answer (score 0):

Use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName):

```
ev.target.element.getElementsByTagName('input').length == 0
```